# MySQL SELECT: Find all languages by Unicode

Tags: python, mysql, select

I'm looking for a rather tricky (for me) SELECT statement that will calculate all supported languages of a font file from a language definition DB.

The unicodes of the font are stored in the list 'unicodes' (we are in Python).
The language DB has two columns, one with the language name and one with one unicode in integer form, like so:

```
(language) - (unicode)
English - 97 #a
English - 98 #b
English - 99 #c
German - 97 #a
German - 98 #b
German - 99 #c
German - 228 #ä
```

My current SQL statement is the following:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT language FROM languagedefinitions WHERE unicode = %s;" % (' OR unicode = '.join(map(str, unicodes())))
```

The problem is that this will put out all languages that are partially supported by the font. A font that that has the unicodes 97-99 will put out both English and German, while one unicode necessary for German (228) is missing in the font.

What I need instead are only those languages that are fully supported by the font, e.g. all unicodes of one language are present in the font.
If one or more unicodes from one language are missing in the font (lets say 228 in the example), German shall not show up.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery. With subquery we choose the languages ​​in which there are unicodes that are not included in the font:

```
SELECT DISTINCT language FROM languagedefinitions WHERE unicode NOT IN (97,98,99)
```

Then we select all the languages ​​that were not selected in the subquery. So, full query will llok like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT language FROM languagedefinitions WHERE language NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT language FROM languagedefinitions WHERE unicode NOT IN (97,98,99);
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL-only subquery solution by NorthCat works, but takes much longer (0.05s) than an iteration implementation in Python using Sets (0.0004s):

```
from sets import Set
# First step, get all languages
languagenames = web.db.dbexec("SELECT DISTINCT language FROM languagedefinitions;")
# Second step, get all unicodes from one language and compare them against the font using sets.Set()
supportedLanguages = []
for languagename in languagenames:
    unicodesPerLanguage = web.db.dbexec("SELECT unicode FROM languagedefinitions WHERE language = '%s';" % (languagename))
    if Set(x[0] for x in unicodesPerLanguage).issubset(Set(unicodesInFont)):
        supportedLanguages.append(languagename[0])
```